# Is it possible to remove an answer without notifing the one who wrote the answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I wrote a very detailed answer within the last 24 hours and I can't find it anymore.

I found a couple of future bugs inside the code of the OP's question. I explained them and how to fix them. It wasn't intended to be the primary solution to the question, but it was important and it took me some time to write it.

Can anyone check it?

Comment: Yes it's possible that your answer is deleted and you weren't notified about it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A code and bugs websites. I request to undelete it.

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136595/anguar2-async-form-validator-doesnt-work - which you won't be able to see, as the question OP deleted it, with this comment on your answer: "Thank you for the answer, but I've got `_zone_symbol__state: null` anyway"

Comment: Did you mean that the question removed?

Comment: Yes, the question's author has deleted it. They can do this as long as there's only one answer and it has no upvotes, to avoid losing valuable content. Also note that *"This may not be the answer to your question"* isn't a confidence-inspiring start to an answer. If you feel the need to put that in bold, maybe ask for further information before answering?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks its a good idea. I would like to have the content of my answer somehow for a future post/presonal content to my computer. How can I get it?

Comment: But don't you already know it? You wrote it! Also, according to the prefix and postfix, you knew it wouldn't be much use when you did so.

Comment: I guess you didnt undersatnd what I asked - can you help me get the content of my answer?

Comment: @StavAlfi Here is a pastebin of the markdown of your answer: http://pastebin.com/8qu2w24n (From the revision of your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40137311/revisions)

Comment: @StavAlfi "Is it possible to remove an answer without notifing the one who wrote the answer?" is very different from "can you help me get the content of my answer?" - I'm not sure how one could have figured what you wanted from what you've wrote. Explicit request to recover content would be more appropriate if it is only thing you were looking for.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Oded wrote that the OP removed the question and answer my question I added addional request to get my answer. I did not write it in the question,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OP deleted the whole question, including your answer:

> **This may not be the answer to your question but it is an imporovment/fixing a future bug(?) to your first method.**
>
> **The problems:**
>
> 1. You subscribe inside the promise but don't unsubsribe after so you will get unexpected behavior after the promise resolved successfully.
> 2. I guess you are expecting the subsription at the first time will happen befor the promise resolved but it may not be the case here. You
>      need to insure that by your self.
>
> **The solution:**
>
> usign the `take(1)` and `toPromise()` methods of rxjs:
>   1. `take(1)` - if `this.usersService.checkEmail(control.value)` will never complete (maby a firebase subscription), use `take(1)` to
>   inforce it to complete.
>
> 2. `toPromise()` - "cast" it to promise so you can return what u need and most importent, insure that what is inside happens **befor** the
>      promise resolved.
>
> Note: If you won't add `take(1)` but only `toPromise()`, your promise
>   will never be resolved and what inside will never be called incase the
>   observable will never complete.
>
> **Code:**
>
> ```
> emailTaken(control: Control): Promise<ValidationResult> {
>     return this.usersService.checkEmail(control.value)
>       .take(1)
>       .toPromise()
>       .then(res=>....);
>   }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> *I hope I'm wrong and this was the behavior you wanted to get in the first place. Incase you didn't here is a better way. There is no need
>   to accept this as an answer.*

Please note that if you have to prefix and suffix your answer with such caveats, you should **just not post it**.

Comment: Thanks. Why cant a user who answered some question, cant see it in his profile? Even if the question removed by someone else? (Why I your help to see my answers?)

Comment: @StavAlfi because you don't have enough rep to [see deleted questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). I believe you *can* see your own deleted questions, and your deleted answers on questions that *haven't* been deleted.

Comment: @NathanOliver but I think they still won't be able to actually click through and see the answer, as the whole question's deleted

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah.  Comment removed.  trying to find the FR to get this feature.

Comment: This makes no sense. I feel that I wasted my time to write a content that I have no access to.

Comment: @StavAlfi had your answer got *any* upvotes in the four hours between it being posted and the OP deleting their question, they wouldn't have been able to do so. The fact of the matter is that it *wasn't* a useful answer to the question, so you *did* waste your time.

Comment: @StavAlfi you've explicitly decided to post non-answer - so at that point you thought it is good/interesting idea. One should expect downvotes/deletion on non-answers. So presumably you got your entertainment value out of the post when you wrote it and should just write that time of. This is similar to going to casino and later *complaining* that you've lost money (instead of boasting) :)

Comment: Hi @Alexei Levenkov consider reading my asnswer befor respoding. I found a bug in his code and I reported to him about that. there is no "entertainment" here

Comment: @StavAlfi if you don't find answering questions entertaining on its own you may soon realize that SO is a very thankless place. I don't know what your reasons for participation are, but if you are not interested in process of answering you may want to find some other way to spend your time - documentation seem to have different model, or just writing blog posts somewhere else.